# configuration parameters of cuda kernel

Tags: c, matrix, cuda, parallel-processing, gpgpu

I have to add two square matrices of `N x N` using cuda program . The book asks to write the configuration parameters for the kernel for the cases :

(a) Each thread must process only `1` matrix element

(b) Each thread producing one output matrix row

(c) Each thread producing one output matrix column

My solutions for the above :

(a)

```
dim3 threadPerBlocks(1,1,1);
dim3 numBlocks(N,N,1);
```

(b)

```
dim3 threadPerBlocks(N,1,1);
dim3 numBlocks(1,N,1);
```

(c)

```
dim3 threadPerBlocks(1,N,1);
dim3 numBlocks(N,1,1);
```

I have no idea whether I am right or wrong for parts (b) and (c) . Please tell me about those and give a brief explanation about them ( if they are wrong , please correct me and explain ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is somewhat fine but you can write in different ways.. All its required is you need to have `N x N` threads so each processes one element.

Alternative for (a) is

```
dim3 threadPerBlocks(N,1,1);
dim3 numBlocks(N,1,1);
```

And in kernel you process as

```
id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;

array[id] = ... ; // process one element.
```

But for (b) it says you need to each thread producing one out matrix row so you need only `N` or `number of columns` number of threads. What you have written with that you will still end up with `N x N` threads.

So you can write this way. One of the possible way there are other ways too.

```
dim3 threadPerBlocks(N,1,1);
dim3 numBlocks(1,1,1);

idx = threadIdx.x ;
```

Then you use a `for loop` to process 1 row in each thread.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
{
    index = idx * N + i ;
    array [index] = ..... ;   
}
```

Similarly you can think for (c) case.